# How should a GARCH (1,1) model look like?

Tags: finance, r

I have a question regarding the GARCH (1,1) model. I have used R to forecast the volatility of some assets. I then plotted the forecasted volatility and the realized volatility on the same plot to see how well GARCH (1,1) performs. I did this for 7 days and 14 days ahead. I also did this for two different time periods, one with 5 years of historical data (Period 1 on the plot) and one with 2 years of historical data (Period 2 on the plot). The realized volatility of course goes up and down, while the forecasted volatility of my model is a straight line, representing pretty much the average of the realized volatility. Is this how it should look like, or should the forecasted volatility also be curved? I thought that it could be curved if I used a GARCH (2,2) or higher model. Also, the forecasted volatility looks pretty similar on both periods, should it be like that? I thought the smaller time period would give me better results (even though the MSE and MAE are smaller on period 2, I don't see much of a difference on the plots).[image]

Comment: How do you measure realized volatility?